# Why does Left outer Join not use the index correctly

Tags: mysql, indexing, left-join

I have two tables called profiles and details. The details table has index on the column city. Here is my query:

```
select * 
from profiles p 
left outer join details d 
use index(details_city) 
 on (p.id = d.pid) 
where (d.city = ‘york’ or p.city = 'york') 
order by p.id
```

When I do the explain on it, I can see that index from details table on city column is not even being used.

Is there any restriction in MySQL that it does not use indexes in such cases.

Comment: Show us the explain? there are many reason. Most comon is table size, small tables doesnt need use index.

Comment: With that where condition, there is no point in the join being `LEFT`.

Comment: @Uueerdo I do need the left join. Let me update my query.

Comment: Unless you haven't edited yet, you still don't need the `LEFT JOIN`; also generally MySQL cannot use indices when `OR` is involved (or, as in the previous state of the query, when leading wildcards are used). The `LEFT JOIN` gives you everything in `profiles`, along with matching `details` if there are any; but your `WHERE` condition removes any join results that did not have `details` records... negating the purpose of the `LEFT`.

Comment: What would be "correct" about MySQL using the `details_city` index? With the query (as it is now in the question), MySQL will *not* use an index with leading column of `city` because the `WHERE` clause contains an `OR`. That condition on `d.city='york'` only partially restricts the rows returned from `details`. The query could potentially return rows from `details` that have `city` values *other* than `'york'`. What is restricted about the rows is that the value in `pid` has to match a value stored in `id` of `profiles`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OR` wrecks all attempts at optimizing.  This should work much faster, especially if the tables are large:

```
SELECT  p.*, d.*
    FROM  (
              -- Get what you can from `profiles`:
              ( SELECT  id
                    FROM  profiles
                    WHERE  city = 'york' 
              )
            UNION  DISTINCT 
              -- Get what you can by starting from `details`:
              ( SELECT  p.id
                    FROM  profiles p
                    JOIN  details d ON (p.id = d.pid)
                    WHERE  d.city = 'york' ) 
          ) AS u
    JOIN  profiles p ON p.id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN  details d ON d.pid = p.id
    ORDER BY  p.id
```

Each inner `SELECT` will use a different index, hence can be optimized.  You will need these indexes:

```
d:  INDEX(city, pid), INDEX(pid)
p:  PRIMARY KEY(id), INDEX(city, id)
```

And you should not need any form of `USE INDEX`.

(And don't use the funny apostrophes: `‘york’`.)

(`OUTER` is optional and has no impact.)

(If you need `city LIKE '%york%', consider`FULLTEXT` instead.)

Why, pray tell, do you have `city` in both tables?!?  Fixing that may lead to the *real* solution.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I have city in both tables and I plan to fix it soon but as of now I cannot touch the structure as it might create havoc because the data in the tables is quite large.

Comment: I will try your solution and will let you know quickly.

Comment: My friend you must be some kind of an SQL Genius.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you would see the same behavior with an inner join. In this statement, the predicate in the WHERE clause negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN. I don't think it has anything to do with the LEFT JOIN.

With the predicate in the WHERE clause... `city LIKE '%...'`, MySQL can't use an index range scan operation. It has to evaluate the value of `city` for every row in the table (or every row that isn't otherwise filtered out.)

Plus, you're returning *every* column from the `details` table, and MySQL can't satisfy that using just an index, it's going to have to visit pages in the underlying table to get the values of those columns.

MySQL is judging a different access plan to have a lower cost than using the index with a leading column of city. There's an equality comparison in the join predicate  **`= d.pid`**.  MySQL can use an index with a leading column to satisfy that.

The index most likely to be beneficial to this query is a composite index:

```
 ... ON details (pid, city)
```

Comment: I removed the 'like' predicate and still it does not use the index when I do the explain on the query

Comment: @john.p.doe But still you havent share that explain result :(

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza 
Hope this helps: 
1, SIMPLE, p, ref, id,  32, const, 66119, Using where; Using filesort
1, SIMPLE, d, ref, FK_details_pid, 15, d.pid, 1, Using where

Comment: @spencer7593 I do appreciate all the info. This is all too good to know. Thanks a lot.